# Hardware accelerated h.264 transcoding on i.MX6

Tags: embedded, video-encoding, video-editing

**Preface**: I have a lot of `.mts` video recordings (mainly 576 to 720 lines) I need to cut and transcode to lower bitrate h.264.  Nowadays I do this on with an all-in-one tool on my 2009 Core2Duo MacBook, but since I updated to El Captain, it takes many hours on that old machine to transcode one hour of video. That's why I look for a new solution.

**Question**: I have a wandboard with an i.MX6quad at hand and I know this machine can do real time h.264 encoding upto 1080p@30fps with it's video processing unit, but search engines didn't help me find a transcoding tool that makes use of the hardware acceleration. Will I need to do this myself? If no: Which tool can I use. If yes: What's the right framework to start with?

I don't expect to find an all-in-one video editing solution for this, but it's okay if I can separately transcode and then use another tool for editing without re-encoding.

Comment: It's not an answer for your question but you could use also ffmpeg + libx264. Both projects include assembler code optimized for ARM.

Answer (score 1):

In case no ready-to-use tool turns up:

Googling finds an open-source library called [libimxvpuapi](https://github.com/Freescale/libimxvpuapi) to access the i.MX6 VPU, including an example program for [encoding](https://github.com/Freescale/libimxvpuapi/blob/master/example/encode-example.c) (where the source frames are procedurally generated).

There also seems to be a similar library provided by Freescale, [here](http://hands.com/~lkcl/eoma/iMX6/VPU_API_RM_L3.0.35_1.1.0.pdf) is the reference manual for it.

You will have to integrate the library and the example program into some other transcoding tool, e.g. [`ffmpeg`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg).

This will need a bit of programming, but maybe you can convince some ffmpeg developers that this is an interesting project, and get them to do most of the work for you, or at least explain the places where you need to hook it into the ffmpeg code.

Comment: It seems my problem has not yet been solved, so your answer is closest to what I want. Thank you. I hope I can find the time to work this out. The bounty goes to you.